# Excel Text to column Programmatically

Tags: excel, vsto, office-interop

We have a product that reads .xls file to extract data. but one problem we have is before we process the files we had to manually convert each column to text type for existing data using text to column wizard. can we do this c# and office automation?

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you could supply some examples

Comment: It would be also nice to know why this must be done, because there may be an alternative.

Comment: we are having an application to process large excel files with, and without doing this formatting its throwing errors

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a macro in the workbook to run the Wizard.
The macro runs along the lines of:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

You may create the macro in Excel itself or [using OA.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303872)

Then when you need to run the wizard, [you can do that from OA too](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306683).

HTH!